# BibTeX natbib with super does not allow using occasional \citet

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using `natbib` with superscript numbered citations as follows:

```
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

It works great when I have the case `This is a reference~\cite{author1999}`. My reference appears as a superscript.

However, I occasionally want write something like: `As shown by \citet{author1999}` where I want the citation written out and not as a superscript. `natbib` in super mode inserts a superscript when using `\citet`.

Is there a way to have `natbib` use `\citet` in regular mode despite being in super mode? Can one change the mode temporarily to not have super and then switch it back on again?

Comment: There is in the [documentation](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/natnotes2.pdf) (here 6 years later...) mentioned the use of `\citenum` instead of `\cite` (or `\citet` or others). This will display the pure reference number `3`. Without superscript or brackets or anything. I believe brackets can just be added manually, which should be doable for occasional uses.

Comment: I added the sort&compress option in \documentclass and this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you want a non-superscript *numbered* citation, you could define a new command `\citenst` that mimicks `\citet` but locally disables the settings of the `superscript` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\citenst}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\NAT@mbox=\mbox
  \let\@cite\NAT@citenum
  \let\NAT@space\NAT@spacechar
  \let\NAT@super@kern\relax
  \renewcommand\NAT@open{[}%
  \renewcommand\NAT@close{]}%
  \citet[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

This is a reference~\cite{A01}.

As shown by \citenst{A01}~\dots

As shown by \citet{A01}~\dots

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! I would like to use your \citet with output either Author1 et al. (2001)^1 or Author1 et al.^1. However, I get (author?) errors. My .bib entries seem to be correct (were generated by BibDesk). Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The first alternative (year plus citation number) is beyond my capabilities. As for the second one: If my MWE works for you, you should try to delete all auxiliary files in your actual document and compile again. If your document still doesn't work, you have to provide a MWE so others can see what exactly you're doing.

Comment: Your MWE works for me with the named style and not plainnat or unsrt. I am very happy with named and your solution. I also got Alan's suggestion to work as well. Thanks to both!

Answer (score 8):

You can't generally mix author-year type citations with numeric citations. But `natbib` provides the `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` commands, so you could construct a simple version for the uses you have:

```
\newcommand{\textcite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}~\citeyear{#1}}
```

And then use `\textcite{<key>}`.  If you just need the author, then you can use `\citeauthor` directly.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I get the warning: Author undefined for citation`boyd2004convex' and an (author?) (year?) in the text. The BibTeX entry is: @book{boyd2004convex,
  title={Convex optimization},
  author={Boyd, S.P. and Vandenberghe, L.},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Cambridge Univ Pr}
}

Answer (score 3):

@lockstep's answer was a great help, but I had a slightly different issue, my search brought me here.

I'm using a superscripted reference style with RevTeX, but I wanted the reference number in the running text, e.g. "further details can be found in reference 7".

So I modified lockstep's code as follows:

`%citenumns provides the reference number for a citation, not superscripted or bracketed
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\citenumns}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\NAT@mbox=\mbox
  \let\@cite\NAT@citenum
  \let\NAT@space\NAT@spacechar
  \let\NAT@super@kern\relax
  \renewcommand\NAT@open{}%
  \renewcommand\NAT@close{}%
  \cite[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother`

now we can have `...further details can be found in reference \citenumns{some_ref}` and get the effect I was looking for.

(added here as this was the most relevant question to place it under, I would have as good as duplicated it)