# References by BibTeX key name

Tags: bibtex, debugging

I've seen [Use BibTeX key as the cite key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8428/use-bibtex-key-as-the-cite-key), and it's quite close to what I'm looking for, but doesn't quite make it - for a start I can't get biblatex to run over my document, and second

What I'm trying to achieve is for the reference list to display, instead of reference numbers (or author-year pairs, but I'm using the `super` natbib style) the key, as in `\cite(key)`.

This is partly a debugging issue, hence the tag, but partly as I'm required to port some existing work to word. I have no influence over that requirement, and I've written something to parse the .tex (excluding equations), leaving me with the cite keys inline - hence I'd like get a references section I can copy into the word document for shared editing.

**Edit - more detail on biblatex**
The error I see is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

If I comment out `\usepackage{natbib}` in an attempt to fix that, I break some [custom cite commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126914/28808) I added.  Replacing those with a simple `\cite` allows it to compile.

The top answer linked above doesn't help much, new keys are generated, which is why I didn't put too much effort into getting it to run before.

**Edit2: The following compiles, but generates new keys.**

```
\documentclass[preview]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{preview}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic,sorting=debug]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Jones_article1,
    author = {A. . Jones and C. D. Smith},
    title = {article1},
}
@article{Bloggs_article2,
    author = {E. F. Bloggs},
    title = {article title 2}
    journal = {Journal of stuff},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
foo\cite{Jones_article1} and bar\cite{Bloggs_article2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example of above code]

**Edit3: This doesn't run:**

```
\documentclass[preview]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{preview}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,style=alphabetic,sorting=debug]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}}\DeclareFieldFormat{extraal??pha}{}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Jones_article1,
    author = {A. . Jones and C. D. Smith},
    title = {article1},
}
@article{Bloggs_article2,
    author = {E. F. Bloggs},
    title = {article title 2}
    journal = {Journal of stuff},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%citenumns provides the reference number for a citation, not superscripted or bracketed
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\citenumns}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\NAT@mbox=\mbox
  \let\@cite\NAT@citenum
  \let\NAT@space\NAT@spacechar
  \let\NAT@super@kern\relax
  \renewcommand\NAT@open{}%
  \renewcommand\NAT@close{}%
  \cite[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
foo\cite{Jones_article1} and bar ref. \citenumns{Bloggs_article2}

%\bibliographystyle(super)
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

instead giving

```
! LaTeX Error: \NAT@open undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.40 ...} and bar ref. \citenumns{Bloggs_article2}
```

Comment: Don't use `biblatex` and `natbib`: `biblatex` is incompatible with virtually all other bibliograpphy-related packages (but it incorporates their functionality and then some).  An [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) would still be helpful at this point.

Comment: @jon, that's why I didn't want to use biblatex.  I now have something that might be an MWE using biblatex, even though I'd like to avoid it, because that breaks some of my other stuff.  It will take a little while to reduce it though.

Comment: @jon, I probably won't use it again, I only meant there was no point in me uploading any code without it: the only example for me to start from used it, and I have no idea of the internals of bibtex or biblatex.

Comment: You are missing @lockstep's `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}}\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{}` from [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8438/8528).

Comment: @Jon, I think you've cracked it - in removing the stuff that was breaking biblatex, that fell away.

Comment: Why this new edit?  the `\NAT*` commands are for `natbib`, and we know that you can't use `natbib` and `biblatex` together..?  You also have `extraal??pha` which won't work.

Comment: @jon it does reduce to that +`backend=bibtex`, so I'll close this - thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want some (but not all!) `natbib` functionalities add the option `natbib` or `natbib=true` (the same) to the call of `biblatex`.

To change the keys in your resulting list you missed to add `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}}\DeclareFieldFormat{extraal‌​pha}{}` in your MWE. There is also a missing comma in your second bib entry.

Your macro `\citenumbers` is not working with `biblatex`.

The following MWE should run and help you:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Jones_article1,
    author = {A. . Jones and C. D. Smith},
    title = {article1},
}
@article{Bloggs_article2,
    author = {E. F. Bloggs},
    title = {article title 2},
    journal = {Journal of stuff},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[preview]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{preview}
\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex
 ,style=alphabetic
 ,sorting=debug
 ,natbib             % to add some natbib functions, nou all!
]{biblatex}
% change key in bib list
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}}\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
foo~\cite{Jones_article1} and bar~\cite{Bloggs_article2}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```