# Can we have regular numbers citations and superscript citations at the same time with natbib?

Tags: natbib, superscripts

I would like to be able to cite some articles as superscript, and some not. 
The problem is that if I try this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers, square, super]{natbib}

\begin{document}

patotos are definetly good for you\cite{who09} and in \cite{who09} they show that they have an harmonious form.

\begin{thebibliography}{0}
\bibitem{who09} Who J F. Nice Book. 2009.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I would have all citations as superscripts while I would like the second cite not to be in superscript because I actually mention the article (but I don't want to present all the writters)... =)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36235/bibtex-natbib-with-super-does-not-allow-using-occasional-citet), your question is probably a duplicate.